# CNNs: First Convolution Operation

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, convolution

I have not fully understood one aspect of the CNNs: is the first hidden layer the same than the convolved image?
I mean, Can we talk about the first hidden layer and the first convolution operation in the same way ? Are they two ways of expressing the same thing ?

Comment: This tutorial will answers all your questions https://cs231n.github.io - https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-1/

Comment: The hidden layer is the CNN layer, I.E the kernels and their weights. The convolved image is the result of applying the convulotions to the image.